# Why is "the" optional in "at home", "at school", or "at church"?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-objects

I was talking to my Spanish friend and found out it's ok to say "en casa" (at home) without needing the article "la (casa)". Then it dawned on me that in English, it's also the same and "the" is optional for the phrases:

- At home
- At school*
- At church
- (Are there others?)

Why is this? It's not for one-syllable words since "at park" doesn't sound right. And of course, most locations fail as well: "at supermarket" sounds wrong too.

**Ironically, "en escuela" (at school) is wrong in Spanish; it needs the article "en la escuela" according to the same Spanish friend.*